# How to renew or refresh SSL certificates of yum "rhui" repositories in GCP?

Tags: certificate, yum, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, rhel-7

Running RHEL 7 in GCP and trying to install packages with yum, all rhui repositories give an error like:

```
https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com/pulp/repos/content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: 
[Errno 14] curl#58 - "SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired.
```

Is there a way to refresh these obviously expired certificates?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the issue:

1. Run the following command to refresh the subscription-manager

   ```
   subscription-manager refresh
   ```
2. Clean the old cache by running the following command

   ```
   yum clean all
   ```
3. Now run any yum command and you should not see that error anymore.